# Smart Map - Outputting locations from a Matrix field for all entries within a single section

Tags: matrix, plugin-smartmap, output

I'm using the Smart Map plugin, and I can't seem to figure out how to output all the locations of my entries from a single section onto one single map.

I think the issue I'm having is trying to get the information out from a Matrix block within each entry or knowing where to start!

The section is 'buildings' which contains all the building entries. For each entry, there is a matrix block called 'buildingContent' which has 5 matrix blocks, and the one I want to pull information from is 'howToGetThere' (last block out of the matrix array). In this block, I have a field 'smartMap' which contains the location of the building.

How would I extract the location from the 'smartMap' field for all my entries and output them onto one single map?

I know the code below outputs the location of one entry (St Bartholomew The Great), but thought it might be useful to include what I've tried so far. I adapted it from the [documentation](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/how-to-use-with-a-matrix-field/):

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug('st-bartholomew-the-great').first %}

{% set locations = entry.buildingContent %}

{% set options = {
     height: 600,
     zoom: 13,
     draggable: true,
     markerInfo: '_includes/mapInfoBubble',
     markerOptions: {
        icon: 'images/map-marker2.svg',
     }
 } %}

{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations[4], options) }}
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! While seemingly tricky, the solution to this should be relatively simple...

Per the [documentation](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/render-a-map-in-twig/), the `locations` parameter can come in a variety of different forms. But the one we're looking for here is this one...

> **As an array of elements**

Collecting Matrix blocks from across different entries can be complicated, but I think you have (fortunately) described a fairly straightforward use-case. We'll need to do the following:

1. Loop through relevant entries.
2. Build *an array of Matrix blocks*.
3. Use that array to render a map.

---

```
{# Initialize locations array #}
{% set locationsArray = [] %}

{# Loop through all relevant entries #}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('buildings').find() %}

    {# Get all relevant Matrix blocks #}
    {% set matrixBlocks = entry.buildingContent.type('howToGetThere').find() %}

    {# Append blocks to locations array #}
    {% set locationsArray = locationsArray|merge(matrixBlocks) %}

{% endfor %}

{# Render map #}
{{ craft.smartMap.map(locationsArray, options) }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Lindsey, this has worked a treat and all the locations are now showing on the single map!